# Building a matrix of indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

(First, the title is REALLY vague - but I can't think of a way to better ask my question. Please feel free to edit the title, then delete this note.)

Suppose I have a matrix `ref`:

```
>> ref
ref = 40 20 90 30
```

And I have a matrix `permuted`:

```
>> permuted
permuted = 20 40 30 90
```

Is there an operation that produces a matrix `idx` such that `isequal(ref, permuted(idx))`? In this case, `idx == [2 1 4 3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[tf, idx] = ismember(ref, permuted);
```

For your example this would indeed yield:

```
idx =
    2     1     4     3
```

Comment: as soon as I asked the question I stumbled upon that. ha. but you get the checkmark as soon as I can click it!